# vega-lite: how to dynamically resize single plots

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I'm looking for a way to set the size on a chart either dynamically or at creation of a single vega-lite chart.  So far, I have tried setting width and height on `spec.config.cell` used for trellis charts which sets the height only, also calling the `width()` and `height()` methods on the `view` object, e.g.

`view.height(200).width(200).render()`

best I can do is get the canvas to resize and crop the chart, but the chart does not redraw to the specified size. I'm looking for it to work with `padding:'strict'` to specify the overall size, not just the size of the data rect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from manually setting the `bandWidth` for ordinals it seems the feature isn't implemented just yet:

https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1356#issuecomment-231825910